# Hive query vs python list processing performance

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

Scenario:
I have a python application which connects to hive database and extracts data, creates sub tables for processing data,drops temp tables etc.. 90% of the processing is done using hive queries which is essentially generated from python code and sends to hive server to execute.

- There is a minimum time spent on sending each query to hive server,
  and returning the status or data. I understand there are unavoidable
  scenarios where the data is in  hive.
- Then there is processing time of the hive query.

There are scenarios where It consumes lot of time to process each query when there are lot of queries to execute in a loop.

Question :
If we assume the data is like some 50k rows. Would it be much faster to fetch 50k rows to python itself(ofcourse the data transfer time is overhead here)- like into a list of tuples- and mimic the join/filter operations hive does and avoid the 10-50 queries run against hive?

Would this be a better approach? Or should i look for hive query optimization techniques. I prefer hive queries as it is convenient to use.

Comment: Personally I would stick to using Hive queries. Hive runs your queries in a distributed fashion that would still be beneficial when your data volume increases. Mimicking Hive in python is a bad idea.

Comment: Is it PySpark? If you can bypass the HiveServer and just hit the metastore&hdfs, it'll be somewhat better